# Trim extra space from column Mysql

Tags: php, mysql, trim

I have a old database in which column categories is stored in bad shape ... with extra space in them, example

```
Hotels     in     London
Hotels        in     Manchester
```

is there a way i can alter this space inside the  table ... if i can remove extra space from categories (middle space) to get output like this

```
Hotels in London
```

Thx

Comment: What is our DB version?

Comment: Hmm the easier would be a trip to *php* as suggests @Chris below

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `REPLACE` function like

```
update table set columnName= REPLACE(columnName,'      ',' ')
```

Comment: the blank space is not same in all columns ... so i cant use this ... ;(

Comment: Or run it multiple times always converting 2->1 space.

Comment: @ChrisChristensen i have 57k data in database ... so this is not possible ;(

Comment: @Barmar can u please explane it ... can i use something like if space is more than 1 ' ' it should come down to 1 ' ' ?

Comment: well, if you run that query then remove one of the spaces in the second argument and run it again and continue to repeat that until you account for all variable amounts of spaces in the column values it will clean all of it. Or write a short script that does it using my method below.

Comment: In the replace method try replacing two spaces with one, and keep continuing it for several times, at the end you will be left out with words separated with single space

Comment: `set columnName = REPLACE(columnName, '<space><space>', '<space>')`. Each time you do this, it will reduce the spaces by half, eventually all the extra spaces will be gone.

Comment: Exaclty what I was trying to explain...Thanks @Barmar..:-)

Comment: @Harinder You prefer to repeat a mysql replace several times, than a single `preg_replace` (followed by update) in PHP. Maybe the `php` tag was not needed?

Answer (score 3):

Pull the data down into values that you can do work on then remove the extra white space using:

```
$foo = trim(preg_replace( '/\s+/', ' ', $foo ));
```

then write it back to the DB.

Comment: Just in case you should add `trim()` around `preg_replace`

Answer (score 0):

I had the similar situation where i had to remove the extra spaces while searching value for a particular field.

I have used replace function of mysql, like this

```
SELECT * FROM `tableName` WHERE post_id = 'xxx' AND replace(`fieldName`,' ','') Like '%JobOppurtunity%' ;
```

Here what replace does, it recursively removes all the spaces in the fieldName and concatenates the field value and then searches my concatenated string after LIKE keyword.

So if I had field value 'Job           Oppurtunity', it will convert it into 'JobOppurtunity' and obviously I would have already concatenated my search string by any string function or regular expression. Like it did this way

```
$txt_search_qry = trim(preg_replace( '/\s+/', '', $txt_search_qry));
```

Answer (score 0):

Another quick and simple method I found is this:

```
REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(columnName,' ',' !'),'! ',''),' !',' ')
```